# Linux terminal equivalent of "start"

Tags: linux, terminal

**Is there an equivalent of the Windows terminal `start` in a GNU/Linux terminal emulator?** For example, if I want to perform some slow terminal task asynchronously while still checking it in a separate shell, I'd do `start process-photos *.jpg` and let that terminal branch off while working in the present one.

Comment: @Bob, I do that, except the tricky part is that stdout still comes to the terminal, making typing new commands somewhat difficult (even happens when I `> /dev/null`.

Comment: Huh, I was pretty sure we had a duplicate, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You can [wrap it in another subshell](http://superuser.com/a/453644/117590). But redirecting works for me - are you sure it's not stderr (`2>/dev/null`)?

Comment: What harm would there be in opening just another shell? Most terms work in tabbed mode these days. I usually have 6-8 shells open.

Answer (score 2):

`start` calls the Win32 shell `ShellExecuteEx` function. There is no direct equivalent in Linux.

However, for your purpose of a non-blocking command, you can add a `&` to the end of a line in `bash` to run the command in the background. For example:

```
process-photos *.jpg &
```

---

I may have misinterpreted your question. The first part of this answer more resembles `start /b`, which launches a new process without a new window.

If you actually wish to launch a new window, you can do so by [launching a new terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/46640/150985) and telling it to execute a command:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e process-photos *.jpg
```